# Is it possible to reference environment variables in launchSettings.json?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to run my code with an executable which is part of a NuGet package. As such, the exe is in my user profile directory. So, the file looks like this:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "UITests": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Users\\MarkKharitonov\\.nuget\\packages\\nunit.consolerunner\\3.9.0\\tools\\nunit3-console.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "@params.txt --where:\"method == LoginSuccessWithCorrectPassword\" ..\\..\\UITests\\bin\\Debug\\net472\\UITests.dll",
      "workingDirectory": "C:\\DFDeploymentSmokeTests\\LocalTestProfiles\\qa56"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to reference the environment variable UserProfile and use it instead of `C:\\Users\\MarkKharitonov`?

**EDIT 1**

I do not want my name to appear in the file at all. This way, it could be reused by others, provided their source code lies in the same folder, which is not a problem. But as long as I have to reference the path to NuGet packages using my name, this file cannot be committed to the source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through much experimentation it seems to somewhat depend on the command that is being run. More accurately what shell the command is run in.

If its in cmd.exe, `%VARIABLE%` should work.

If its running under powershell then it would be `$env:VARIABLE` or `${env:VARIABLE}` when in a double quoted expandable string.

I would suggest something along the lines of the following.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "UITests": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "${env:UserProfile}\\.nuget\\packages\\nunit.consolerunner\\3.9.0\\tools\\nunit3-console.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "@params.txt --where:\"method == LoginSuccessWithCorrectPassword\" ..\\..\\UITests\\bin\\Debug\\net472\\UITests.dll",
      "workingDirectory": "C:\\DFDeploymentSmokeTests\\LocalTestProfiles\\qa56"
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming UserProfile is C:\Users\MarkKharitonov